# facebook open Graph: Created_time in future

Tags: filter, facebook-opengraph

**First question:**

Im wondering why an entry in facebook could be created in the future. that is very strange,
in my opinion:

Exactly I am talking about this [entry](https://graph.facebook.com/249887210752_10150466510880753).
Maybe a failure from facebook ?

**Second question:**

During this, I have got some problem to filter this out, and additional other entries (which are correct):

In an open-graph request, I can request specific fields `(me/wall%fields=...)` , but can I exclude some IDs ? As an example, I have a feed-wall and want to exclude one person of this. (thats not exactly what I want, but the general idea is the same)

Answer (score 0):

1) please raise a bug on developers.facebook.com/bugs - giving full repro steps about the request you made to create this post object

2) no. you can't specify IDs to exclude - you'll have to do this on your side after you've received the response.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I dont have to search further. Great answer.
I will check my first problem directly with facebook. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to filter those IDs out with your code.